# How to print one error after going through invalid index index in list based on user input

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Basically going through a list a printing related indexes to the list based on the `mrp_number` input.

I want to print an error statement or at least have it loop back to the user having to input the correct `mrp_number` again. My issue is that this is a large list with a good amount of rows with missing `mrp_numbers`. How do I loop through this list and have the error print once only?

I've done the else statement but it'll keep printing error as it reiterates through the list with a missing mrp_controller. I tried learning try and exception handling but I've no clue.

```
def mrp_assignment():
    mrp_number = input("Enter MRP Controller Number ")
    for row in polist:
        purchasing = row[0]
        material = row[7]
        mrp_controller = row[8]
        description = row[9]
        if mrp_number in mrp_controller:
            print(mrp_controller, purchasing, material, description)
        else:
            print('error')
```

I expected one error to be printed but I got multiple errors printed

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a break after print('error'). This will break your for loop if error occurs.

Comment: Hey Haydar, In case the asker is not familiar with `break`s, would you mind explaining these too?

Comment: Here is how break works. Thank you for your suggestion @Steven. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement

Comment: Sorry, I do understand what break is. Please read my code. If I enter an MRP number that doesn't exist in the 3rd list but exists in the 100th, it will break the entirely and print an error and that is what I DO NOT WANT. I want to make it where if It doesn't meet the criteria for example: 90\260 is what an MRP number should be...then it will break and ask to input again.